# Using lambda racket

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

```
Design a function that consumes a [Listof Number] and checks if 0 is in the list.
```

I want to figure this out using `lambda`. I've been reading the book, and this is what I've came up with so far. I hope im close.

```
(define (five? lon)
  (..... (lambda (x)
           (= x 5))
         lon))
```

how would you finish this (if right)?

Comment: Is it 5 or 0? the problem description states that it's 0, but the code uses 5

Answer (score 1):

Yup! Checkout the `ormap` function.

procedure

```
(ormap proc lst ...+) → any
  proc : procedure?
  lst : list?
```

[From the Racket documentation:](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=ormap#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/map..rkt%29._ormap%29%29)

> Similar to map in the sense that proc is applied to each element of
>   lst, but
>
> - The result is #f if every application of proc produces #f; and
> - The result is that of the first application of proc producing a value other than #f, in which case proc is not applied to later
>     elements of the lsts; the application of proc to the last elements of
>     the lsts is in tail position with respect to the ormap call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number that's being searched is `5` (as inferred from the code and not the problem description) - there's a procedure that already does what's being asked, it's called [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._member%29%29):

```
(member 5 '(1 3 5 7))
=> '(5 7)
```

Which, according to the documentation:

> Locates the first element of lst that is equal? to v. If such an element exists, the tail of lst starting with that element is returned. Otherwise, the result is #f.

But if we were to implement a similar procedure from scratch, this is how the solution would look, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define five?
  (lambda (lon)
    (if <???>                 ; is the list empty?
        <???>                 ; then the number is not in the list
        (or <???>             ; otherwise the current element is 5 or
            (five? <???>))))) ; the number is in the rest of list
```

Don't forget to test your code:

```
(five? '())
=> #f
(five? '(1 2 3 6 7 9))
=> #f
(five? '(1 2 3 5 7 9))
=> #t
```